# Merge request profile link validation is fair to middling

Tags: bug, merge-accounts

Bungled an attempt to add a login to my account recently and created a sock instead.  Decided not to give myself sweet sockpuppet rep, so I tried sending in a merge request.

[image]

You can see from the image that the validation for the profile URL is a bit overzealous, and won't accept a URL without the slug on the end (in my case, **/will**).

Mayyyyybe it's a feature, but I'm thinking it's a bug.

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking I should send an email to **LOL!!!** to see who responds.